# FTP connection - OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON

Tags: linux, windows, ftp

Recently my Windows server got upgraded from 2012 to 2019, Since then my FTP script (with error handling) is falling to capture all the FTP messages. The script was working fine prior to the upgrade.

The below log is captured while trying to connect to the destination server Manually.

```
C:\Users\>ftp
ftp> open
To server01
Connected to server01.xx.xxxxx.com.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
User (server01.xx.xxxxx.com:(none)): ftpusername
331 Password required
Password:
230 User logged in.
ftp> cd "/remote/directory/path"
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> lcd "T:\local\diectory/path"
Local directory now T:\local\diectory/path.
ftp>
```

The below log is from my script that re-directs to a location (STD_OUT)

```
open 
To server01
User (server01.xx.xxxxx.com:(none)): 


cd "/remote/directory/path"
lcd "T:\local\diectory/path" 
Local directory now T:\local\diectory/path.
pwd 
257 "/remote/directory/path" is current directory.
Quit
```